# Submit form laravel using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am trying to add comment using AJAX technology but I have an error: 
`Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8888/blog/public/comment/add the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`
Here is my code: 
View:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'col-md-6','url' => '/comment/add', 'id'=>'comment')) }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{$id}}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 form-group">
                                {{Form::label('name', 'Imię')}}
                                {{Form::text('username', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'name', 'name'=>'name'))}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                                {{Form::label('message', 'Wiadomość')}}
                                {{Form::textarea('message', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'message', 'name'=>'message', 'rows'=>'5'))}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 submit form-group">
                                {{Form::submit('Wyślij', array('name'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-orange'))}}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller:

```
public function addComment()
{
        $this->layout = null;
        //check if its our form
        if(Request::ajax()){
            $name = Input::get( 'name' );
            $content = Input::get( 'message' );

            $comment = new Comment();
            $comment->author =  $name;
            $comment->comment_content = $content;
            $comment->save();

            $postComment = new CommentPost();
            $postComment->post_id = Input::get('post_id');
            $postComment->comment_id = Comment::max('id');
            $postComment->save();

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
            );
            return 'yea';
        }else{
            return 'no';
        }
}
```

AJAX:

```
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $( '#comment' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = $(this).find('input[name=name]').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: host+'/comment/add',
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( msg );
        });

    });
});
```

And the last one routes:

```
Route::post('comment/add', 'CommentController@addComment');
```

Anyone have an idea where is the problem and why I can't submit my form?

Comment: value of host in javascript ?

Comment: `<script>        var host = "{{URL::to('/')}}";    </script>` so it has `http://localhost:8888/blog/public`

Comment: A 500 error means there's likely to be a useful error message in your Laravel log. Check there.

Comment: You don't need the host, just try it like url: '/comment/add'

Comment: have you checked laravel log ?

Comment: Here is my log: http://pastebin.com/KFGwR0pC
@baao it doesn't work because then in error I have http://localhost:8888/comment/add

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are not posting any data,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host+'/comment/add',
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    });
```

The error you are getting is that the columns in DB cannot be null.

Try to change your ajax call to this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host+'/comment/add',
        data: { name:name, message:message, post_id:postid }, 
        success: function( msg ) {
            alert( msg );
        }
    });
```

Change this

```
var name = $(this).find('input[name=name]').val();
```

to

```
var name = $('#name').val();
```

and fetch the message and the post id:

```
var message = $('#message').val();
var postid = $('#post_id').val();
```

---

**Complete ajax block:**

```
   $('#comment').on('submit', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var name = $('#name').val();
       var message = $('#message').val();
       var postid = $('#post_id').val();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: host+'/comment/add',
           data: {name:name, message:message, post_id:postid}
           success: function( msg ) {
               alert( msg );
           }
       });
   });
```

And finally, add an ID to the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="{{$id}}">
```

---

Send data back from Laravel controller, eg.

```
    // ........

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
        );
        return Response::json($response);  // <<<<<<<<< see this line
    }else{
        return 'no';
    }
}
```

This will send the data in your response back to your ajax request.

Then, alter your ajax success function:

```
 // .......
 success: function( msg ) {
     $("body").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
 }

 // ..........
```

You will now see that a new div was created in your `<body>` including the created response. If you want to show the newly created post, just create it as the ajax response and append it to any element in your page.

Comment: It works I dont have any errors but I have to refresh page to see new comment. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you only pass data to the controller, if you want to see the new comment directly, you need to send it back to your ajax request, catch it in the success function and output it. I will edit my post with a little example, I'm sure you will figure it out with that, give me a second. @Zobo . Please accept the answer if it has helped you

Comment: I've edited it. @Zobo try if you have success, if not feel free to ask again!

Comment: Ok I've got it but I have one more question. This is my SinglePostController http://pastebin.com/jfKU1dKy where I have relationship between comments and single post. How can I send back to ajax content of added comment and add +1 to comments that are belong to this post?

Comment: One option would be sending back the values of Input::get('/.....') and using them, as this is the new post. If you need posts that aren't by the same user, just add the db query from the other controller to the one you call with your ajax and send the data as your response (in both scenarios)

Comment: How can I add second controller to ajax? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Which code? I did it with first scenario but I want to know how to do it with second one.

Comment: Where I have to put it in?

Comment: I think if you send your data this way, you will need to take care of `csrf` token also.

Answer (score 17):

Just modifying the ajax block of [baao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27346402/). You can pass data as serialized.

```
$('#comment').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host+'/comment/add',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

All the field values of the form can be passed using the `serialize()` function.